# VB.NET StreamReader Only Returning One Char On ReadLine/Initialization Error?

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

I am having a slight mishap in my vb.net (.NET Framework 4.5) app. On startup with this code, nothing changes, and when I trigger the event later to change label11, I only get the letter e, and I can't for the life of my figure out what is wrong with the code. The file is encoded in UTF-8 I believe, but changing the encoding doesn't seem to help. steamDisplayName, steamID64, and steamID32 are defined as strings at the beginning of the program. Here is my code that is executed on startup:

```
Private Sub mainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\config\loginusers.vdf")

    steamDisplayName = reader.ReadLine(3)
    steamDisplayName = steamDisplayName.Replace(Chr(34), "")
    steamDisplayName = steamDisplayName.Replace("PersonaName", "")

    steamID64 = reader.ReadLine(5)
    steamID64 = steamID64.Replace(Chr(34), "")

    steamID32 = steamID64.Substring(0, 3) - 61197960265728

    Label11.Text = "Welcome, " + steamDisplayName
    My.Settings.steamID = steamID32
    reader.Close()
End Sub
```

And here is my C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\config\loginusers.vdf:

```
"users"
{
    "76561198041432370"
    {
    "AccountName"       "snip"
    "PersonaName"       "tsunami"
    "RememberPassword"      "1"
    "Timestamp"     "1407351554"
    "WantsOfflineMode"      "0"
    }
}
```

Comment: ReadLine doesn't take any parameters. So when you call ReadLine(x). It is reading the next line and then grabbing the xth character in the string

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you define the loginusers.vdf file yourself? I may be able to suggest a better alternative, because they way you are doing it is extremely complex and shouldn't be so. Also, if you are trying to convert the number to 32-bits by subtracting you are doing it the hard way. The Int32 class has a Parse function, pass it the string, it will return the value. Int32.Parse(someString).

Comment: Further to what TheShaman said, why are you trying to pass numbers to `ReadLine`?  Are you trying to read lines at specific indexes in the file?  You can't do that.  You have to read all lines up to and including the line you want and simply discard the rest.

Comment: I was unaware of that, thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

This is NOT a code writing service, however, the code below should help you, it's completely untested, so please check it carefully first.

```
Private Sub mainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim lines As New System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\config\loginusers.vdf")

    Dim id As Long = 0

    For Each line in lines

        If line.Contains("PersonalName") Then
            Dim parts = line.Split(Chr(34), SplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            steamDisplayName = parts(1)

        ElseIf Long.TryParse(line.Trim.Replace(Chr(34), String.Empty), id) Then
            steamID64 = id
            steamID32 = steamID64.Substring(0, 3) - 61197960265728   ' What is this for?!

        Label11.Text = "Welcome, " & steamDisplayName
        My.Settings.steamID = steamID32
    Next
End Sub
```

If Dharman could stop editing my posts from 9 years ago, it would be appreciated.

Comment: I do appreciate the help, thanks. I'm getting the error Type 'System.IO.File.ReadAllLines' is not defined. :/ Also, that's to convert the 64 bit steam ID into the 32 bit version. It's the shortest method.

Comment: ReadAllLines should be available in Framework 4.5... it's in 4.0, doubt they removed it.  Weird.